# Azure ARM template keyvault override in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

How can I override the ARM template Azure keyvault reference in Azure DevOps? I have ARM template which has reference like:

```
"KeyVaultSecret": {
  "reference": {
    "keyVault": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/214124-1241-526-645-lele/resourceGroups/KEYVAULT-RG/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/KeyVault"
    },
    "secretName": "VerySecret"
  }
}
```

but I would like to override the id and/or secretName in some cases.

Comment: Use convertfrom-json and convertto-json cmdlets to process the template file...

Comment: My ultimate idea is to override this in the Azure DevOps release pipeline so doing conversions sounds like something that is out of scope.

Comment: Don't forget that you can run custom PowerShell scripts in the Azure DevOps pipelines `;-)`!

Comment: I can but I like to keep some of the stuff in the ARM templates. Hence the need for overriding parts of the ARM template parameters

Comment: Are you using Azure Devops or are you going to deploy your ARM template manually?

Comment: I am doing both. However I think the same way for overriding can be used with Azure DevOps and powershell.

Comment: why you do not want to use template [parameters()] and you want to override the values?  You can create 2 parameters for KeyVault ID and SecretName with default values and pass those parameters to template when needed

Comment: I want to control the used key vault in VSTS release pipeline. I am creating the key vault on the fly so it does not exist before the release starts.

Comment: @Kamsiinov could you explain a little bit more ? I do not see how it blocks you from using ARM template parameters, you can override them on the step of ARM Resource Group Deployment and use output variables from the previous step of KeyVault creation. Even you can pass your reference object through parameter and inside template you will have something like : "KeyVaultSecret": "[parameters('keyVaultSecretReference')]".

Comment: @IvanIgnatiev-MSFT I am trying to override the template parameters in the VSTS "Override template parameters" box. In this example case I would use switch "-KeyVaultSecret" but I do not know what to put after that when I want to reference the keyvault secret.

Comment: @Kamsiinov If I understood everything correctly : -KeyVaultSecret { "reference": { "keyVault": { "id": "/subscriptions/214124-1241-526-645-lele/resourceGroups/KEYVAULT-RG/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/KeyVault" }, "secretName": "VerySecret" } }     and you can use VSTS variables for variable places , I suppose you will need something like { "reference": { "keyVault": { "id": $(kvReferenceId) }, "secretName": $(kvSecretName) } }   , in your template you need to use  "KeyVaultSecret": "[parameters('KeyVaultSecret')]"

Comment: @IvanIgnatiev-MSFT i tried with "-KeyVaultSecret { "reference": { "keyVault": { "id": "/subscriptions/$(SubscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$(Vault)/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/$(keyVaultName)" }, "secretName": "adminuser" }}" but it is not understood correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use nested templates to do that, just provide a parameter with value, and then use nested template to invoke that. [Here's](https://github.com/4c74356b41/bbbb-is-the-word/blob/master/_arm/parent.json#L154) that is using nested templates to get KV values. you can easily replace hardcoded value which I link to with a parameter or with expression, which would allow you to do what you need.

You might go as far as implementing a "switch" like approach to determine needed value based on resource group name.

Comment: That does not still allow me to give the keyvault id as parameter. Or override it in the Azure DevOps.

Comment: it does, read the answer, if you have any questions - get back to me

Answer (score 1):

We use powershell to read in the parameter template as a JSON object `$Template` then replacing the ID value with the appropriate value and writing out the updated object to a Temp file.

```
$Template["KeyVaultParm"].reference.keyvault.id = "<NewReferenceID>"
```

This allows us to use the same template with Prod/Dev and have different KeyVaults while using the same ARM template/parameter files.

Comment: I would rather use less powershell and more built-in functions.

Comment: If possible, please provide the complete code snippet.