# How to override the key vault reference parameters in ARM Template using "ARM Template Deployment" task in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I have developed logic app using VS2019. In that I’m reading the secret value from Azure Key Vault using the below lines of code:

**logicapp.parameters.json**

```
"azuretables_sharedkey": {
  "reference": {
    "keyVault": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/XXXX-KV-NonProd"
    },
    "secretName": "StorageAccountSharedKey"
  }
},
```

I have configured Build and Release pipeline to deploy the logic app into Azure using “**ARM Template Deployment**” task in Azure DevOps. But I want to override the above key vault reference parameters in Azure DevOps Build and Release Pipeline.

So, can anyone suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed key vault reference code from `template` file. And then integrated Azure Key Vault with `Common Library` in Azure DevOps CI/CD pipelines by following this [documentation](https://devkimchi.com/2019/04/24/6-ways-passing-secrets-to-arm-templates/).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass keyVaultName, keyVaultSecretName and keyVaultSecretValue from Azure DevOps library and update key vault using below ARM template code.

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
  "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVaultName'), '/', parameters('keyVaultSecretName'))]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('keyVaultName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "value": "[parameters('keyVaultSecretValue')]"
  }
}
```

You can access key vault secret value in ARM template for function/webapp using below code statement. It refers to value in current secret version.

```
"value": "[concat('@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=', 'https://',parameters('keyVaultName'),'.vault.azure.net/secrets/',parameters('keyVaultSecretName'))')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

On the **ARM template deployment** task, there is an option "**`Override template parameters`**" can be used to override the template parameters.

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

Here is case for the same question: [Azure ARM template keyvault override in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946403/azure-arm-template-keyvault-override-in-azure-devops)

Comment: Bright, that one I know but I want override the above mentioned key vault reference parameter. For that, can you please provide sample snippet.

Comment: Hi @Pradeep, I have updated mu answer with more information. Please check it.